# Identify inserted row values to run stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a table `Table_A` and a stored procedure `Calculate_B` that does some calculations on the data in `Table_A` and update `Table_B` accordingly.

How can I run the stored procedure `Calculate_B` only on the newly inserted rows in `Table_A` and insert the new rows accordingly in `Table_B`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Calculate_B
AS
----some sql statements-----
SELECT * FROM Table_A;
```

Edit1 :
The inserts are made from a windows application which uses entity framework to add data in the database

Comment: Where does inserting rows into `Table_A` come in? YOu said you did calculations on `table_A` to `UPDATE` `table_b`. Where are there `INSERT` statements? That SQL Procedure tells us nothing about the problem either.

Comment: As presented, you can not. You must do this at the time of insertion. You can use a trigger (which requires a certain level of expertise) or you can use an output clause with your insert statement. You would then need to "share" those rows with your procedure (or move that logic into the insertion code).

Comment: @SMor I have been looking into triggers, but triggers do not understand on how to return the primary keys of the inserted rows from a trigger and then pass the primary keys as parameters to the stored procedure

Comment: For `IDENTITY` values, you are far better off using an `OUTPUT` clause in the `INSERT` statement, and inserting those outputted rows into a table variable/temporary table.

Comment: Please show us the tables and some sample data. As it stands, we're just guessing.

Comment: @Larnu Can you share an example?

Comment: Not in the comments, no, @KrushikaTapedia . And I can't paste an answer that would be suitable without more information in the question.

Comment: @Larnu the inserts are done from a windows application with uses entity framework, so I need to identify the inserts and run the stored procedure on the inserted rows only. Does that help?

Comment: You're going to therefore need to change the application to use a Stored Procedure then @KrushikaTapedia .

Comment: @Larnu Unfortunately I do not have access to the source code of the application to make changes

Comment: @KrushikaTapedia, I believe you're looking for [`Change Tracking`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) on `Table_A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another column to your table of type `Bit` and call it `digestedFlag` (or anything else you like)

Then, edit your `Calculate_B` Procedure and make it only update rows with `digestedFlag=0`.
Once the calculation is done (Or during) - update all your rows `digestedFlag` to be `1` (So they won't be calculated on next run)

Comment: How can I run the stored procedure when there is a row insert? Using a trigger?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were the one calling `Calculate_B `. 
In that case yeah, you could use a trigger. Here's a guide
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/